# Creating time series data from pandas dataframe and known time interval

Tags: python, pandas

This data has no date time or other useful columns like other questions address.

I have a pandas data frame ( or single series)  returned without date information like so :

```
      [10:1]
0    2.264555
1    3.555655
2    4.023047
3    3.500272
4    3.033678
..        ...
152  3.808607
153  4.222035
154  5.205624
155  5.025041
156  5.711009
```

What I do have is the starting time and the time interval between each row.

Basically startingTime : 2020-02-19T02:54:29.000Z  and timeInterval : "0.05" (5 seconds)

How could I go about creating an x,y style format like [[datetime, value], [datetime, value]] ?

Is this a situation where you would typically do the opposite of what i'm thinking and inject the computed date time as column in the data frame first?

Comment: timeinterval 50 microseconds or 5 seconds? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a datetime column with fixed time interval:

```py
import datetime

starting_time = datetime.datetime(2020,2,19,2,54,29)
td = 5  # timedelta
df['datetime'] = [starting_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*td) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Then you can apply this to convert your values into list:

```py
list(zip(df['datetime'], df['Column']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create timestamp like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_list = [str(datetime(2010, 2, 19, 2, 54, 29).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S Z')) + str(timedelta(seconds=5*x)) for x in range(0, len(df))]
```

**Result:**

```
['2010-02-19 02:54:29 Z0:00:00',
 '2010-02-19 02:54:29 Z0:00:05',
 '2010-02-19 02:54:29 Z0:00:10',
 '2010-02-19 02:54:29 Z0:00:15',
 '2010-02-19 02:54:29 Z0:00:20',
 '2010-02-19 02:54:29 Z0:00:25',
.
.
.
]
```

then

```
df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', date_list)
```